# Deconvolution and Polynomial factoring using the FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, deconvolution

I've been trying to implement a general N dimensional deconvolver for various engineering applications and some math curiosities.

For speed and simplicity I've decided to try and do this with help of the fast fourier transform and the fact that for circular convolution ($*$), we have:

$$(f_1 * f_2)(t) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f_1)\mathcal{F}(f_2))(t)$$

then assume we know $f_1*f_2$ and $f_2$ we try and find $f_1$ by a naiive divide strategy:
$$ \mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac{\mathcal{F}(f_1 * f_2)}{\mathcal{F}(f_2)+\epsilon}\right)$$

If we use circular convolution, how do we avoid effects like the one below:

$\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\2\\1 \end{array}\right][1,2,1] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&1\\2&4&2\\1&2&1\end{array}\right]$ divided/deconvolved by $[1,2,1]$ (should be $\left[\begin{array}{c} 1\\2\\1 \end{array}\right]$):

$$ans = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}        
5/6&1/6& -1/6&        1/6&       -1/6&        1/6\\
5/3&        1/3&       -1/3&        1/3&       -1/3&        1/3\\
5/6&        1/6&       -1/6&        1/6&       -1/6&        1/6
\end{array}\right]$$

An "ordinary" convolution (with zero-padding) between $ans$ and [1,2,1] would not give us an correct answer:
$$[1,2,1]*ans = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
2&1&0&0&0&0\\
4&2&0&0&0&0\\
2&1&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right]$$

We can check that circular convolution between $ans$ and [1,2,1] would give us a shifted or rotated version of the 3x3 filter above ( and plenty of 0 entries ):
$$[1,2,1](*_C)ans = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}
2&1&0&0&0&1\\
4&2&0&0&0&2\\
2&1&0&0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right]$$

Is there an easy remedy to this? I have a few ideas for engineering solutions to this, but they are very ad-hoc.

---

**Edit:** Found one way that seemingly solves the problem above. There was one particular bug when deconvolving down to a singleton dimension, this seemed to be helped with the hint in the comments ( just to sum over the singleton dimension ).

Another example, to calculate the

$$f_1*f_2 = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
-1&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right] \hspace{0.5cm}f_2 = \left[\begin{array}{rr}0&1\\-1&0
\end{array}\right] \hspace{0.5cm} \text{gives:} \hspace{0.5cm} f_1 = \left[\begin{array}{rrrr}0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$
Which corresponds to the $$(x^4-y^4) = (x-y)\sum_{i=0}^3x^iy^{k-i}$$

Here the second bug created two constant diagonal lines, but it was due to an error in how I handled the origo in the FFT-routines.

Comment: Row-wise sum of $ans$ gives the intended result of $[1, 2, 1]^T$.

Comment: Yep in this case it does. But the filters are very simple.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but deconvolution of FIR filters (as your $[1\,(2+\varepsilon)\,1]$ kernel) can be implemented very efficiently ($O(n)$) with what is called "direct spline filtering" or "bidirectional recursive filtering". This is explained [here](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~mignotte/IFT6150/ComplementCours/Splines.pdf). I've used this technique for several image processing applications and it works marvelously.

Comment: @WimC: Wow that is an impressive complexity. I should check it out. 

I found something which I think solves my problem, but it is very informal and ugly so I'm still curious for a good explanation.

Comment: I don't understand your problem description. How is the answer 2-D? Are you convolving a 2-D matrix with a vector? What effects are you talking about? If it's correct in the circular convolution sense, then how is not correct? Are you talking about linear convolution?

Comment: I am talking about a general $n$ dimensional convolution. The example is in 2D. I will clean it up a bit.

Comment: I still don't understand why it's only correct in the circular convolution sense. Convolution is a linear operator and as such has a matrix representation. Say we are convolving $a,b\in\mathbb{C}^1$, then there is a matrix $A$ such that $a \ast b = A b$. To deconvolve, what we need is $A^{-1}$, whether we are talking about circular or linear convolution. Also, the FT is an isomorphism, so I don't see how it can give you an answer that is only correct in one sense.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to use the Fast Fourier Transform for speed, but as far as I know it only ensures circular convolution to become multiplication. What I was looking for was a zero-padded-convolution and then try and change the functions before (and after) if needed to make it still work with convolution. You are right I could just find $A^-1$ or divide a vector by $A$ and I am doing that in other places too. In this particular case I was just curious if I could get it to work for zero-padded convolution using something that relied on circular convolution.

Comment: Multiplication in the frequency domain will give you linear convolution if you zeropad prior to taking the FFT. Is that what you are talking about?